# How can add html code to a function node NODERED

Tags: javascript, html, function, nodes, node-red

looking for some help here
I am starting in nodered and i can't find the info that i need to advance.

I want to create a flowNode that contains HTML code inside for use that new node in a templateNode

**FUNCTION NODE**

```
flow.set("flowVariable","<h2>example</h2>");
var obtainData= flow.get("flowVariable");
msg.payload = obtainData;
return msg;
```

**TEMPLATE NODE**

`{{{flow.flowVariable}}}`

When i call the variable in a template it worked and show me the html code (in this case `<h2>example</h2>`, but i need to add a large html, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <title></title>   
    <link> 
    <style></style>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

how to add the HTML code in a flowNode?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a string, you can add it just the same way you did the `<h2>example</h2>`

```
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
           '<html lang="en">\n' +
           '<head>\n' +
           '   <meta charset="utf-8">\n' + 
           '    <title></title>\n' +   
           '    <link>\n' +
           '    <style></style>\n' +
           '</head>\n\n' +
           '<body></body>\n\n' +
           '</html>';

flow.set("flowVariable", html);
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing strings that contain quote (") you are better of using single quotes (') this applies to set up HTML or MySQL queries.

So you're function code will be:

```
flow.set('flowVariable',' <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">     <title></title>   <link> <style></style></head> <body></body></html>');
var obtainData= flow.get("flowVariable");
msg.payload = obtainData;
return msg;
```

Comment: cool thanks!, but what if i want to i dont know, put an entire html website on a variable, this is the best way or is another one?

There is another way to define a flow node that contain multiple information inside? imagine for example inspect this webpage, take all the html and put it in the flowNode variable...

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I tested now, my habit is to use Change nodes for writing/reading context data, so it is maybe a little messy.
Okay, so I saved this page on my RPI 3, used a file node to read it, then used Change node to set flowVariable from msg.payload, it's quite simple to convert it in the function node, but I think I proved the concept.

One more method is to completely copy the HTML in the Change node and set flowVariable to  string (your HTML)
The best way would be this one.

Answer (score -1):

i was practicing and yep, i define a flownode with "flow.set("Example", data);

but then i delete the node, deployed but still can call it

thanks a lot!